# Running MongoDB on heterogeneous cluster

Tags: mongodb

We're currently trying to find a solution, where we can host tens of millions of images of various sizes on our website. We're evaluating Riak and MongoDB. Currently Riak looks very nice, but all the servers in the cluster should be homogeneous, because Riak treats each node equally.

It is a bit hard to find information about MongoDB regarding to this, except the fact, that you can set a priority on the nodes. My questions are:

1. What is the consequence of creating a MongoDB cluster composed of machines with wildly varying specifications (cpu, diskspace, disk speed, amount and speed of memory, network speed)?
2. Can the MongoDB cluster detect and compensate for such differences automatically?

I'm also open for ideas for other solutions, where heterogeneous cluster would work nicely.

Comment: First time i heard Riak treats all the servers as identical, which IMO is not a good practice, as hardware gets cheaper and you are likely to get better machines in time.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the consequence of creating a MongoDB cluster composed of machines with wildly varying specifications (cpu, diskspace, disk speed, amount and speed of memory, network speed)?

Each shard in MongoDB is its own `mongod`, an isolated MongoDB in itself.

It isn't tied by the performance of others, so say you have a shard that requires more power, you can just upgrade its hardware and job is done. MongoDB likes environments like this and actively promotes them.

> Can the MongoDB cluster detect and compensate for such differences automatically?

It doesn't need to detect but it will automatically compensate, naturally without any work within the `mongos` or `configsrv`

In fact you will find you can even run different MongoDB versions.

Comment: I mean: when a node A is performing badly (lots of traffic), will other nodes (B and C) help A, by taking more traffic in the cluster? Is that what you mean?

Comment: @manum No that activity is dependant upon your shard key, they are not replicas but instead shards, they hold a unique range of data. I assumed your question was about sharding

Comment: On the [sharded cluster balancer](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-balancer-administration/), does it work equally well on heterogeneous cluster as non heterogeneous cluster?